# Permitir acceso FTP a enlace simbólico fuera de la "jaula" del usuario

Tags: linux, ftp

Hola utilizo vsftpd bajo debían y habilitando `chroot_local_user` eh enjaulado a todos los usuarios en su carpeta home mediante:

> local_root=/home/$USER/ftp

Ahora e insertado un enlace simbólico dentro de su carpeta ah otra carpeta fuera de su directorio home pero no pueden acceder a el mediante FTP (si mediante shell) ¿Alguna idea de como configurar correctamente esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pienso que no puedes hacerlo porque un link simbólico no es realmente un punto de montaje sino una referencia a otro archivo. Ves la referencia, pero como el archivo está fuera de tu alcance no puedes entrar a esa "carpeta".

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un verdadero punto de montaje usando la opción `bind`.

```
mount --bind /mi_carpeta /home/nombre_usuario/mi_carpeta
```

Eso durará hasta que se reinicie la máquina, por lo que te aconsejo probar mi sugerencia, ver si resulta y en caso afirmativo, crear una entrada en tu `/etc/fstab` señalando

```
/mi_carpeta /home/nombre_usuario/mi_carpeta none defaults,bind 0 0
```

Eso sobrevivirá a los reinicios.